# MDCSwipeToChooseのフレームワーク適用方法について

Tags: swift, xcode

Swift初心者なのですがMDCSwipeToChooseを使用したアプリを作成したいと思い、Qiitaの下記記事を参照させていただき、同じものを練習で作成したいのですが、`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`のエラーが出てしまい、実行できない状況です。
素人なりに調べてはみましたが、解決方法がわかりません。
どなたか問題の原因とその解決方法をお教えいただけませんでしょうか。

参照：
http://qiita.com/ysk_1031/items/894d9652097b1c8be639

環境：
OSX 10.10.01,
Xcode 6.4
cocoapod 0.37.2

私の行った手順：

1. xcodeで新規プロジェクトを適当なフォルダに作成。
2. そのフォルダにpod 'MDCSwipeToChoose'　と記載したPodfileというファイルを作成
3. コマンドラインでそのディレクトリに移動し、pod installと実行
4. xcodeで上記プロジェクトを開く
5. プロジェクトにPodsとFrameworksというフォルダが追加されていることを確認
6. プロジェクトのViewController.swiftが入っているフォルダで新規ヘッダファイル追加
   （ヘッダファイル名はBridgingHeader.h)
7. BridgingHeader.hの中に

   ```
   #import <MDCSwipeToChoose/MDCSwipeToChoose.h>
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   ```

   を追記（すでにある記載は残す）
8. Build Settingsの設定のTRAGETの内、ペンと定規で三角形のアイコンのObjective-C
9. Bridging HeaderにBridgingHeader.hを記載。
10. すでにあるViewController.swiftに上記のQiitaで紹介されているコードで丸ごと反映（コピーアンドペースト）
11. 実行(command + R)

結果：
build時
`linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`エラーが出てしまいます。

Answer (score 2):

> 4.xcodeで上記プロジエクトを開く

とありますが、CocoaPodsを利用している場合はプロジェクトではなくワークスペースを開く必要がありますが、プロジェクトを開いてるのではないでしょうか？

（プロジェクト名）.xcworkspace というのが作られていると思いますので、それを開いて再度やってみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた通りプロジェクトを開いていました。ワークスペースを開くことでビルドが通りました。

ただ、実行しても画面が白いままで想定通りの表示ではない状況です。
デバッグウインドウに下記のプリントが出ています。
`Unknown class _TtC8xxxxx14ViewController in Interface Builder file.`
ひとまずビルドはできるようになりましたので、もう少し原因を確認してみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 上記も解決しました。
画面が白いのは参照コードをコピペした際クラスがViewControllerではなくSwipeViewControllerになっていることに気づいていませんでした。
ViewControllerをclassに設定することで動作しました。
`Unknown class _TtC8xxxxx14ViewController in Interface Builder file`はstoryboardを使用しないことで解決しました。